# Appium sendKeys really slow on android

Tags: java, android, testing, appium

I'm currently testing an application using Appium on an android device (appium version: 1.2.4.1, java-client: 2.1.0). I'm using the following code to send some text in a textField:

```
   driver.findElement(By.name("Name")).sendKeys("My Name");
```

and it works fine just it takes it too long to actually send the text on the textbox (usually 7 seconds). I was wondering does anybody know another way to send text on a textField that takes less?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, when posting questions about Appium always remember to specify the following information:
- OS where Appium is installed and running
- Are you running tests on real device or simulators/emulators?
- Which platforms are you testing on? iOS or Android?

Comment: it depends upon the machine OS as well. I executed the same code on windows and Linux , but there is a difference of about 50%.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by using adb to send text instead of appium!It is really fast!

```
try {
     textElement.click();  
     new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"adb", "-s", "YOURDEVICEUUID", "shell", "input", "text", "YOURTEXTASINPUT"})
       .redirectErrorStream(true)
       .start();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Same way you may use this for Click,clear,install,uninstall etc.. there may be some need to sleep thread for sync issues but it is only 50ms which is too less than 5 seconds which appium takes!
You may use DDMLIB to make this adb call instead of ProcessBuilder!

Comment: Tried doing this, however, the text does not appear on the text field and there are no errors that are displayed, how can I debug this?

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Name")).Click();
driver.Keyboard.SendKeys("My Name");
```

This should run faster then your method.

Answer (score 2):

This capabilities helped me to reduce the time of inputs on Android

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreUnimportantViews", true);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("disableAndroidWatchers", true);
```

You can find more here https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#android-only

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing slow automation on Appium is common because Appium is based on a client/server architecture. Network issues can influence the performance of a test (unless you are running your test in the same machine where Appium is installed).

I can tell you that I have also experienced problems with slow tests on Appium. It usually happens on simulators/emulators by the way.

### Send keys as part of a UX scenario

If your test needs to send keys as part of a User Experience scenario, then `SendKeys` is your only option. This method does not simply set a value in a textbox, it actually behaves like a user pressing keys and sending keys to a textbox.

If this is what you need, then you need to understand what is happening a network level because this is what your problem is about. Also consider that this method can be slow on its own sometimes (this is my experience).

### Setting a text is not important for the UX scenario being tested

In case the step of setting a textbox's value is not a core part of your automation for the specific test being considered, you an always do achieve this by means of `ExecuteScript` which lets you execute a Javascript code in your app. I am assuming you are automating the WebView context.

```
int result = driver.executeScript("
    try {
        var el = document.getElementById('<your-txtbox-id-here>');
        el.value = '<your-text-here>';
        return 0;
    } catch {
        return 1;
    }
");
```

Java does not support multiline strings so the previous is a prettyprint of the following:

```
int result = driver.executeScript("try{var el = document.getElementById('<your-txtbox-id-here>');el.value = '<your-text-here>';return 0;}catch{return 1;}");
```

This method will return `0` in case the string was successfully set, otherwise `1`. It should be faster because the driver will not send each key separately but execute the script in an anonymous function and get back its return value.

Comment: I am getting exception saying executeScript is not yet implemented. please specify version of client and server.

Comment: same delays here, with everything running on the same machine, I doubt it is related to the network, especially since clicking on button is very fast, and only inputting text is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following capabilities inorder to have appium keyboard(and not the physical keyboard)

```
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
```

Comment: interesting, but no, it does not help.

Comment: It works for me that's why i propose it ;) 
May be you will use it next time !

Comment: yes, sure. that allows the device to not display a keyboard, which is interesting in itself

Comment: It was typing approx 1 char per second which is deadly slow. After adding these setCapabilities it started typing 10 chars per second. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sendKeys` with the `setValue` method available in later versions of appium:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Name")).setValue("My Name");
```

It is much faster in my experience.

Comment: While `setValue()` is definitely much faster, it doesn't support unicode - something you should keep in mind if using `setValue()`.

Comment: @Vanessa Reagan
I am using appium 2.0.beta57. But I could not see the method setValue("text") for the WebElement.
What I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

For new commer, in the Appium version 1.9~, both method `executeJavaScript()` & `setValue()` works so good, and you can consider to use it.

```
// use js
executeJavaScript("$('#" + fieldId + "').val(testData);

// use setValue
$(By.id(fieldId)).setValue(testData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved the speed of my test (written in Python) using:

```
driver.set_value(myElement, "My Name")
```

instead of:

```
webElement.send_keys("My Name")
```

If you are using Java, it will be something similar to:

```
driver.setValue(driver.findElement(By.name("Name")), "My Name")
```

Another approach could be with adb... (This is the fastest one but you have to use another thing besides appium)

```
//1st - Click at your WebElement 
driver.click(driver.findElement(By.name("Name")))

//2nd - Using adb send your text
//adb shell input text "My Name"
adb shell input keyboard text "My Name"
```

Comment: The adb method you mentioned has changed. It should now be: `adb shell input keyboard text "My\ Name"`. Also note that the adb way doesn't support unicode characters (although if you have your keyboard set to unicode it might be possible, I just don't know how to do that).

Comment: I was not aware of: adb shell input keyboard text... I am still using the other method but I guess is deprecated? Thanks and I will move to your way. And about Unicode, I think I never tried to type unicode with ADB. But again I guess you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Set in capabiblities:

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appium:disableWindowAnimation", true);
```